# Lookup person from list of people

Tags: excel, list, report

I am not an experienced Excel user, so I was hoping to find some help here.

I have a sheet containing the names of reports, the type of report (PDF or Excel), and a list of recipients. See example below:

| Title | Type | Recipients of Report |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Weekly Sales | PDF | John Doe, Jane Doe |
| Monthly Sales | PDF | John Doe, Jane Doe, Carl Smith |

I want to be able to pick a person from a drop down list (or input field) and see the reports that are sent to this person.

Is there any smart way to do this?

Thank you for helping!

I have tried to Google a way to do this, but as mentioned, I am new to Excel and I have no clue how to figure this out. Any tips/help is more than welcome!

Comment: Well, if you have a unique list you can do a data validation drop down, then use find() to test for the selected name. Find() only works on one cell so a helper column will be needed. Then index() with match() or an if() to get the title.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you have Excel 365, check functions FILTER. It may be helpful here. If you got an older version of Excel, I'm afraid that manual filtering or doing something with a macro is your only option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a quick attempt, without using FILTER():

[image]

Cells I2 to I5 is the unique list that the data validation in cellE2 uses.
If find() gets a number then if() returns the name, if find() does not find the name it produces an error so iferror() changes that to zero.

So you can copy instead of typing:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND(E$2,B2,1),0)>0,A2,"")
```

Then I would do a concatenate to produce a list based on results in column C that are not blank, and put that in cell F2.
Something like:

```
=substitute(A2&", "&A3&", "&A4&", "&A5&", "&A6,", , ",", ")
```

which will work for the range A2:A6. You can extend that.

Comment: This solution was just what I was looking for, thanks a lot!